# Recaptcha v3 take Token out of function

Tags: java, web, recaptcha

I have a quick question, I have captcha v3 on my webpage in order to verify the user is not a bot and can send a contact form.

On my personal website I provide some features, and currently working on showing the User the trust score from captcha which was provided to them. Now to the main problem, I cant get the Token value out of the captcha part in order to create a link where they can check the code.

this would be my code, if you would have a better solution to show code to the User, would be great:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LcYp9cZAAAAAG4Gs6efgl8ss9SIfCqHBHkYmHV9"></script>


<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('6LcYp9cZAAAAAG4Gs6efgl8ss9SIfCqHBHkYmHV9', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
        document.getElementById("token").value = token; 
        
      });
    });
    var loc = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LcYp9cZAAAAAHyrhfLx6gyiWO8dImUTSPbT_xy5&response=";
    document.write('<a href="' + loc + token + '"><button>Test</button></a>');
    </script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable for token and assign the value generated from the grecaptcha.execute function. Then you can access the generated token value outside of the function.

OR

As your code token value can be accessed like follows

```
document.write('<a href="' + loc + document.getElementById("token").value + '"><button>Test</button></a>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, could you show me a code sample, I am not that deep in to Java in order to implement this:

"You can define a global variable for token and assign the value generated from the grecaptcha.execute function. Then you can access the generated token value outside of the function."